# How do I find words from a list with specific letters?

Tags: python, list

first list:

```
word_list = ['Jack','Caroline','Jane']
```

second list:

```
letter_list = ['a','c']
```

I want to save all the words that contain the letters 'a' **AND** 'c' in a third list.

The third list should look like this:

```
third_list = ['Jack','Caroline']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
word_list = ['Jack', 'Caroline', 'Jane']
letter_list = ['a', 'c']

third_list = [word for word in word_list if all(letter in word.lower() for letter in letter_list)]
print(third_list)
# ['Jack', 'Caroline']
```